# Replacing values in a huge dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a huge dataframe (600,000 x 12,000) and I need to replace some values. 
I have tried as below, but it takes more than 3 hours:

```
mydata[mydata = “AA”] <- 0
mydata[mydata = “AB”] <- 1
mydata[mydata = “BA”] <- 1
mydata[mydata = “BB”] <- 2
mydata[mydata = “--”] <- 5
```

I also tried this, but doesn’t work:

```
mydata <- as.data.frame(apply(mydata, function(x){replace(x, x == "AA",0)}))
mydata <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x){replace(x, x == "AB",1)}))
mydata <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x){replace(x, x == "BA",1)}))
mydata <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x){replace(x, x == "BB",2)}))
mydata <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x){replace(x, x == "--",5)}))
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how much RAM do you have? I failed to create such data.frame on 32 Gb machine.

Comment: @cyberJ0g You are right.  I wasn't thinking about the size

Comment: Could it be that you are using data.table? For data.frame the equal signs would ve wrong...

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) and show expected in- and output. Your code should throw an error.

Comment: PaulaF, you can still use R.  Load/create the data in chunks if possible.  For example, subset the DF into 10 6e4 x 1.2e4 chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the data.frame requested is rather big to fit in memory of a reasonable desktop machine, and perhaps R is not the tool for this job.

In any case, for a data.frame 1000 times smaller than requested, here is one way to do it.

First simulate some data:

```
set.seed(10001)
mydata = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("AA", "AB", "BA", "BB", "--"), 7200, replace = T), 
                       nrow = 600, ncol = 12))

head(mydata)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1 BA AB AB BA BB BB BA AA BA  BA  AA  BA
2 BB AB AA BA AA AA BB AB --  --  AA  --
3 AB -- -- BB BB -- BA AA AB  BA  AA  AB
4 -- BB BA AB BB BA BA BB AA  --  BA  BA
5 BB AA BA BB -- BA AB BB AA  BB  BB  --
6 AB -- AA BB BB BA -- -- AB  --  AA  AB
```

Then transform each column of the data.frame using `apply` together with the `mapvalues` function from the `plyr` package:

```r
library(plyr)

# Vectors of values to transform
from_this = c("AA", "AB", "BA", "BB", "--")
to_this = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 5)

# Apply mapvalues to each column of data.frame
## I'm assuming that you want the new values to be of numeric type
new_mydata = apply(mydata, 2, 
                   function(x) as.numeric(as.character(mapvalues(x, from_this, to_this))))
```

This gives:

```
head(new_mydata)
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
[1,]  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  0  1   1   0   1
[2,]  2  1  0  1  0  0  2  1  5   5   0   5
[3,]  1  5  5  2  2  5  1  0  1   1   0   1
[4,]  5  2  1  1  2  1  1  2  0   5   1   1
[5,]  2  0  1  2  5  1  1  2  0   2   2   5
[6,]  1  5  0  2  2  1  5  5  1   5   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like you have a factor here and I think it might be better to work with renaming your factors. I found [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/) nice page where they give some examples how you can do that. 
If you want to end up with a numerical column you could think about doing something like `as.numerical()` after you replaced your levels.

Comment: Please avoid to post single link without posting as answer relevant code.